# Which preposition is correct here: "The bar graph illustrates budget distribution __[among or to]__ different categories in five organizations"?

Tags: prepositions

*The bar graph illustrates budget distribution **[among or to]** different categories in five organizations*

So in the OALD, it is shown that *"distribution"* often goes with *"among somebody"*. However, I feel like **to** is also a viable choice here, and since it's *"categories"*, not *"somebody"*, I'm not sure if *"among"* is okay.

Comment: *Between* sounds more natural but it's not clear-cut. A budget is distributed *to* people/organizations, but you want to emphasise that the chart shows how it's divided between the different categories. (Although if it shows a subdivision within the categories you might even go for *in*.) Some people might prefer *among* but I wouldn't; *between* vs *among* is controversial but [see this usage note](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/between).

Comment: Distribution is a noun which means "the action of sharing something out among a number of recipients" - so there's no need to repeat "among" here, since it's already understood in the meaning of that word.  I would simply use **for** here.

Comment: @BillyKerr Your answer seems to be in contradiction to Stuart's because by what you said, "between" is unsuitable, too.

Comment: I didn't say it was unsuitable. Among and between are usable, just a little redundant.